Does Islam allow my father to
My aunt gifted me, a baaligh teenager a phone. My father has decided to not let me use it until I finish highschool/become an adult (aka 18). Does Islam allow this?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Quran says:

وَ قَضَىٰ رَبُّكَ أَلَّا تَعْبُدُوا إِلَّا إِيَّاهُ وَ
بِالْوَالِدَيْنِ إِحْسَانًا إِمَّا يَبْلُغَنَّ عِندَكَ الْكِبَرَ
أَحَدُهُمَا أَوْ كِلَاهُمَا فَلَا تَقُلْ لَهُمَا أُفٍّ وَ لَا
تَنْهَرْهُمَا وَ قُلْ لَهُمَا قَوْلًا كَرِيمًا
Thy Lord has decreed you shall not serve any but Him, and to be good
to parents whether one or both of them attains old age with thee; say
not to them Fie neither chide them, but speak unto them words
respectful(17:23)

But Quran totally does not say to obey them. So, if you want to fully obey Allah, it is better not to use it until you reach the age of 18. Surely, you will receive great rewards from Allah both in this world and the hereafter because this is a challenging and hard divine test. Alternatively, you can use it secretly without his knowledge, so at least you will not disrespect him according to the Quran but this may not be suitable for your training.

Taking one ayah from the quran about parents and saying it does not specify to obey them isn't a clear proof. Islam teaches us to respect and obey our parents out of love and appreciation, only disobeying when it comes to haram matters.

@userNameAsString it is not only one verse. Quran totally does not say to obey them. but says to respect them. do you have any verse to support your claim about obeying them? even this verse says to disobey them in case of shirk: https://quran.inoor.ir/fa/ayah/29/8/ we have verses about disobey but no verse about obeying. so we have no duty to obey them. but only respect. so we can disobey in some cases but while being respectful and also obeying in most cases that have no conflict with Islam and our conditions. I insist any disobey should be with full respect. instead saying no say OK I think
